# Из json в массив

Tags: php, laravel

Как можно привести json вида {"id":[1,3,11,27]} к массиву. Я получаю из бд данные с json, а затем нужно составить запрос подставляя в него id, котороые указаны через запятую.

Например:

```html
$array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($array as $id) {
  $teacher = DB::table('teacher')
  ->where('teacher.id', '=', $id)->get();
}
```

Comment: Вот поневоле возникает вопрос - а нафига всё это делать частями? что бы сразу от БД не получить требуемые финальные данные? с JSON он работать умеет...

Answer (score 0):

Как? Ознакомиться с документацией например.

- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.object.php

```
<?php
$json_string = '{"id":[1,3,11,27]}';
$json = json_decode($json_string);
print_r($json);

foreach ($json->id as $id) {
    var_dump($id);
}
```

Вывод

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 11
            [3] => 27
        )

)
int(1)
int(3)
int(11)
int(27)
```

1. Во первых json_decode возвращает объект, если вторым параметром не указан true
2. У тебя в JSON явно указан ключ `"id"` равен массиву, а не просто `[1,3,11,27]`
3. Зачем ты делаешь много запросов, когда можно использовать `` WHERE `teacher.id` IN (1,3,11,27) ORDER BY `teacher.id` ``  и потом просто отсортировать полученные данные. Представь себе что id вернёт 1000 id'шек, ты будешь делать 1000 запросов и застрелишь SQL ?